# JSFiddle CSS problem? Link border around images

Tags: css, jsfiddle

I have the same code in both Plunker and JSFiddle:

- [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/9VXV8QGE8h4VBHBAWEWN/)
- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/facechomp/vc47koLn/)

As you can see, the link borders around the images are wrong in both cases within JSFiddle, but they are proper in Plunker.

Is this a problem with JSFiddle? If so, is there some CSS I can use to fix it, without breaking it elsewhere?

Here is the code. HTML:

```css
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.one {
  border: solid 2px gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
}

.one:hover {
  border-color: #FF9900;
}

.two {
  border: solid 2px gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.two:hover {
  border-color: #FF9900;
}
```

```html
<h3>Problem One - with float</h3>
<p>This is a problem in jsfiddle, but not plnkr</p>
<a href="#" class="one"><img src="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img6-thumb.jpg"></a>
<a href="#" class="one"><img src="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img5-thumb.jpg"></a>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
<h3>Problem Two - without float</h3>
<p>This is a problem in jsfiddle, but not plnkr</p>
<a href="#" class="two"><img src="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img6-thumb.jpg"></a>
<a href="#" class="two"><img src="https://en.js.cx/gallery/img5-thumb.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: `.one img, .two img {
  max-width:100%;
}`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b5we6tp4/

Comment: I would expect the fiddle version to be correct as you are setting a width with border and padding equal to the size of the image so I would expect for the image to overflow the div.  Perhaps jsfiddle adds border-sizing whereas plunkr doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[stender's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244684/stender) answer is the best, use always em unit:

```
.one img, .two img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

because JSFiddle added border. If you inspect code you will see:

```
*, ::after, ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```